# mysql SELECT not working shows error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-select-db

I am getting the below error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'testing order by id'
```

Here is the main page..

```
echo "<div ><a href='secondpage.php?title=".urlencode($row['title'])."'>".wordwrap($row['title'], 35, "<br />\n", true)."</a></div>";
```

and here is the second page the error appearing on. the address bar reads `http://localhost/secondpage.php?title=more+testing`

```
 <?php
   $mydb = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM test where urlencode(title) =".$_GET['title']" order by id ";
     $result = $mydb->query($sql);
  if (!$result) {
  echo $mydb->error;
 }


 ?> 
 <div>
 <?php
 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){

 echo $row['firstname'];
 }
 $mydb->close ();
 ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you show query output?

Comment: In SQL query, when you want to put a complete string inside it, put 2 single quote character at the begin and end of it. `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='$value'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `urldecode` to decode the encoded string in your query:

```
$title = urldecode($_GET['title']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where title = '$title' order by id";
```

I'm assuming you have a column named `title` in your `test` table.  I don't think MySQL has `urlencode` function unless you have a procedure by that name which functions exactly like PHP's `urlencode`.

**Update:**

Thanks to @GeorgeLund, who pointed out the point of SQL Injection.  Important topic which I missed earlier during answering your question.  Please have a look at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

For the very least please update your code to following:

```
$title = urldecode($_GET['title']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title); // Addition
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where title = '$title' order by id";
```

Comment: I do have a column named title and your code works thanks very much.

Comment: Supplying example code with sql injection flaws to newbies is totally irresponsible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where urlencode(title) ='".$_GET['title']."' order by id ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE urlencode(title) = ".$_GET['title']." ORDER BY id ";
```

You missed `.` leads syntax go away.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know SQL does not have function `urlencode` and why would you even want to `urlencode` the column name?

Also to store the encoded title string which is received from the last page you should decode the encoded title

So here is what I think you meant to do.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE title = ".urldecode($_GET['title'])." order by id ";
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code using urldecode

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test where title =".urldecode($_GET['title'])" order by id ";
```